# jQuery Loading message pageLoad BlockUI

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loading

Using Block UI --> [Block UI](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/)

I'm trying to make the "Loading" message appear before the page starts to load and while the page is loading.

See this jsFiddle --> http://jsfiddle.net/wx9F3/22/

Narrow the search down to a couple of part numbers using the textboxes at the top and then click "reset". The page will start to load and THEN the "Loading" message appears. I need this to happen before the page starts to load and while the page is loading.

```
$('#clearBtn').on('click', function() {
    $.blockUI({message: '<h3>Loading</h3>',timeout: 2000}); 
    $('.modx').val('').trigger('keyup');
});
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because your function on triggered with keyup event it making the browser gag, I do not have the time to check the whole function, but you should look into it.

As a quick fix, do not set timeout for blockui, and add a delay in calling keyup, like this:

```
  $.blockUI({message: '<h3>Loading</h3>'}); 
  setTimeout(function(){$('.modx').val('').trigger('keyup');},500);
```

Than at the end of keyup function just add a call to release the blocked ui, like this:

```
 $.unblockUI();
```

See the full fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Nc9SW/), but please I will like to STRETCH out this is just a patch, to get it working you should really sort out your function which causes the halt.

Emil

Comment: Thank you! I have to trigger the keyup function in order to reset the filters. This was actually a suggestion by the creator of Table Sorter 2.0

Comment: Sorry probably I have expressed myself wrongly it's not the trigger which makes the browser struggle, it is the whole filter reset function. As an alternative to your actual table try to have a look at datatables.net imho it's the best table handling framework.